# How do you change the background colour of a modal in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I can't get the background colour to go past my image component. How can I make the entire modal page that same pink-ish colour?

```
<Modal visible={modalOpen} animationType='slide' style={{backgroundColor: '#B6A3B0'}}>
  <View style={{backgroundColor: '#B6A3B0'}}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {setModalOpen(false)}}> 
      <Image 
        style={{ width: 50, height: 50, left: 20, bottom: -50}}
        source={require('../assets/removeblue.png')}/>  
    </TouchableOpacity> 
  </View>
</Modal>
```

Here's an image of what it looks like with this code:

[image]

Comment: Do `style={{backgroundColor: '#B6A3B0', flex: 1}}`

Comment: Thank you! that fixed it

Comment: Cool. Nice to know that 